# Incorrect port, user and password for my futon couchdb.html

Tags: desktopcouch

my ~/.local/share/desktop-couch/couchdb.html has the wrong values for port, username and password. It seems quite likely that this is due to a reinstall without formatting /home. My Python scripts work well with my desktopcouch, but I would like to use Futon as well. What is the most elegant way of recreating that file with proper values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was really quite simple; just delete the cookies from localhost. (If you have other local webuis running, you might want to manually find the one that points to _utils.) After doing so, the next time you login it will ask for a confirmation and it will remember the username, password and port to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

That file is regenerated each time desktopcouch starts up.  This is necessary because the desktop instance of couchdb is run on a random port.  If you can't log in via that file, it probably means that desktopcouch is not running (it is started on demand rather than on login).

You should be able to get desktopcouch to start by running an application that uses it.  Alternatively, you can activate it by sending a dbus message to it:

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply --type=method_call \
    --dest=org.desktopcouch.CouchDB / org.desktopcouch.CouchDB.getPort
```